# How can I enable my footer widgets on all pages in my wordpress child theme?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I bought the cultivate theme from restored316designs.com. By default, the footer widgets do not appear on the homepage. I want my footer widgets to show on my homepage. Right now, they only appear on my blog page. How can I enable them on my home page?

Where the footer widgets appear:
LifeBeforeEternity.com/blog

Where I want them to appear:
LifeBeforeEternity.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For many themes you can find the code being used to generate a widget section and just copy and paste it to the area where you want it.

For example in [my theme](https://github.com/pacificpelican/theme12) the widget section is declared with this code:

`<?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-1' ); ?>`

Try to find the similar code being used to generate your widgets that you want [in whichever template file generates the blog page--blog.php or somewhere??] and copy it (along with any HTML needed to contain it) to the place where you want it.

So, for your theme, try finding the widget code that only runs for the blog page and copying it to somewhere around the bottom of the file that generates your home page, probably index.php--see if that works.

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it a try!

Comment: Thanks so much for pointing me in the right direction! The author had an action called "remove footers on static page" on the index.php, so all I had to do was delete that bit of code! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

the blog page and home page is exatly the same at me

Also, you need to contact the theme builder and ask, you may need to modify the theme to do that

Comment: Yeah. I think the author might try to charge me for customization, so I thought I'd ask y'all smart people. Lol :D